# What does it mean to say that the source code is always available to interpreters?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, interpreter

From **Thinking in C++ - Vol. 1**:

> Interpreters have many advantages. The transition from writing code to
>   executing code is almost immediate, and ***the source code is always
>   available*** so the interpreter can be much more specific when an error
>   occurs.

What does the bold line mean?
Does it mean that the interpreter cannot work unless whole of the program is in memory? Which means we cannot divide the program into modules and then have the modules interpreted as and when needed (like we do with compilers)?

If yes, then what's the reason behind this?

---

### UPDATE:

From **Thinking in C++ - Vol. 1**:

> **Most interpreters require that the complete source code be brought into the interpreter all at once.**

So, does this now indicate what I wrote above?

[image]

Comment: you know javascript ? Python ? Ruby ? Lua ?

Comment: In case of interpreted languages each line of code is interpreted and executed. While in case of compiled languages there are two stages, compilation and linking.Compilation converts code to object code. The object code is further linked by linker to produce an executable.So if you compare compiled and interpreted languages yes source code is always available to the interpreter because there are no stages involved, interpreter evaluates each line of code and executes it.

Comment: Source code interpreters perform their namesake: Interpret source code. In doing such, it should be obvious they need *the source code* they're interpreting and as the text implies, that source is available for reporting detailed error state. Compiled+Linked code needs no such source access once the final executable is created, so short of integrated debugging information and logging facilities, error states can be significantly more obtuse to identify with utmost clarity.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly real question to me...I see no reason to close it.

Comment: What's to see?  The person writing 'Thinking in C++' isn't keen on interpreters, and has a slightly warped view view of them.  Perl is an interpreted language.  It reads and compiles its program at run-time and then executes what it compiled.  It can load extra modules while it is running (it compiles the new modules on demand) if desired, but usually it isn't. The interpreter may not have the whole source loaded in memory; it just needs all the source available (it can read one file at time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that the interpreter cannot work unless whole of the program is in memory?

No. The whole program need not to be in memory. the parts are loaded into memory as and when required.

> Means we cannot divide the program into modules and then have the modules interpreted as 
>   and when needed (like we do with compilers)?

You can very well modularize your programs. but the required modules should be availble when required by interpreter.

And the bold line: **the source code is always available**

It means that it's the source code that runs, i.e. converted to machine specific instruction at run time. *line by line* without being converted to a different (intermediate) format. (as is done by compiler)

From Wikipedia:

> An [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) may be a program that uses one the following strategies for program execution:
>
> 1. executes the source code directly
> 2. translates source code into some efficient intermediate representation (code) and immediately executes this
> 3. explicitly executes stored precompiled code[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) made by a compiler which is part of the interpreter system
>
> **Efficiency**
>
> The main disadvantage of interpreters is that when a program is interpreted, it typically runs more slowly than if it had been compiled. The difference in speeds could be tiny or great; often an order of magnitude and sometimes more. It generally takes longer to run a program under an interpreter than to run the compiled code but it can take less time to interpret it than the total time required to compile and run it. This is especially important when prototyping and testing code when an edit-interpret-debug cycle can often be much shorter than an edit-compile-run-debug cycle.

Comment: so, basically it is only a matter of "speed", nothing more? and why does it say that ***"so the interpreter can be much more specific when an error occurs."***? Both have the source code, one has the raw other has the translated, how is it making the difference?

Comment: `speed` is one criteria to use interpreter. and yes, it can directly refer to source code when error occurs. but when run-time runs compiled code, it can't refer to exact line where error occured.

Comment: My answer still holds. also check the limitations of those interpreters where complete source code is brought into memory. And, i'm sure that here `complete source code` doesn't mean the whole project code but the required modules only.

Comment: Ah, well, the question wasn't about the limitations, it was about understanding the "generic" working of the interpreters. Also, `i'm sure that here`<- this doesn't help. Please provide the links from the standards to support your comment. No offense intended.

Comment: The generic working of interpreter is explained in 3 ways (see my answer). An interpreter can choose any one of them. `Wikipedia` should be a trustable source to confirm that. The line you quoted starts with `Most` i.e. not all interpreters follow that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21712/discussion-between-azodious-and-anisha-kaul)

Comment: `The generic working of interpreter is explained in 3 ways (see my answer).` Which line there says that the interpreter needs all the source code in the memory at once? Third?

Comment: I don't think continuing in chat is needed here. We are discussing "on topic" stuff, not some offtopic nonsense. This discussion is related to the question and may help the future readers.

Comment: The point is you are asking same question again and again. and i'm just rephrasing my answer. you are talking about implementation detail while those 3 ways are about the design decision.

Comment: So, why don't you point which line (with links) in your answer talks about "having the full source code in memory" or vice versa? No need to rephrase your answer, simply point out the exact line and I'll read it.

Comment: None. that's the point. you can import full source code in memory by following any of the approach mentioned. but that's not mandatory. either bring all src at one go or bring as required.

Comment: let me give you can example and it may help you to understand more clearly. lets say you are using an undeclared variable `i` at two places. interpreter can't give errors for both the places at one time cause it will execute one line at a time. now it is varied from interpreter to interpreter whether other use of `i` is in memory or not. you can't make a generic decision about it.

Answer (score 2):

For *compiled languages*, when you run the program, you don't have the source code — you have compiled machine/byte code and this is executed on the machine (or VM in the case of Java).

Interpreters work on the *source code* and immediately interpret it and executes it using some internal mechanism. Since their working data is the source code itself, it is always available to them.

Comment: Re "Interpreters work on the source code and immediately interpret it to the native code and execute it.", most modern interpreters work on byte code generated from the source code. E.g. Python, JScript, Racket. Also, they don't usually interpret "to the native code". The interpreter is often not native code, and it's just directed by the code that it interprets, it does not translate that code to native code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Regarding the first part, I believe the question is about theoretic aspect of interpreters - that work on source code. Regardingthe last part, you are right, let me fix it.