# Why are debuggers much more specific when an error occurs as compared to compilers?

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-construction, interpreter

From **Thinking in C++ - Vol. 1**:

> Interpreters have many advantages. The transition from writing code to
>   executing code is almost immediate, and the source code is always
>   available ***so the interpreter can be much more specific when an error
>   occurs***.

Interpreter always works directly on the source code (after translating it line by line into machine code) so that may be the reason that it can be much more specific when an error occurs.

From: [What does it mean to say that the source code is always available to interpreters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037090/what-does-it-mean-to-say-that-the-source-code-is-always-available-to-interpreter/14037160#comment19392261_14037160)

> speed is one criteria to use interpreter. and yes, it can directly refer to source code when error occurs. ***but when run-time runs compiled code, it can't refer to exact line where error occured.***

Now, what about the debuggers?
GDB works on the output produced by the compiler, so here GCC and GDB have same files to work on.

**Why is GDB able to show the exact error on the exact line (during run time) then as compared to the compiler?**

Comment: "Interpreter always works directly on the source code without translating it into some format" - surely not.

Comment: @H2CO3 Now is it correct?

Comment: The compiler doesn't run the code. It just compiles it. Many errors only occur when specific _input_ is given to the program, and the compiler can't possibly try all possible combinations of input just to see if they cause an error. This is the difference between compile-time errors (e.g. syntax errors) and run-time errors.

Comment: @jogojapan Who "runs" the `a.out` file?

Comment: @jogojapan so, why can't the operating system produce the specific run time errors when GDB can? Both work on the same file - a.out?

Comment: Also Compiler will check only syntatical errors. Syntatical errors are suggested by line number while compiling.
And gdb checks logical error. for that gdb needs symbol tbale information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is GDB able to show the exact error on the exact line (during run time) then as compared to the compiler?

These are two different softwares with different purposes. First you should understand this.

> so here GCC and GDB have same files to work on

Not exactly, Debugger needs some more files generated during compilation. (called symbols). These symbols are bridge between compiled code and source code.

I'm not much sure of GCC but it should have `debug` and `release` build options.
When you compile in debug mode, by default symbols are generated that help GDB to debug. but in release mode, be default symbols are not generated and GDB can't debug a release build.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. This may be a dumb question and I need to study more.

Comment: In GCC, the `-g` option is used to add debug symbols for GDB (or other debuggers) to use.

Comment: @jogojapan Yes, I remember that now. :)

Comment: @Anisha Kaul: Yes. learning is a constant part of IT industry. and as they say: There are no dumb questions, so keep up the spirit and ask your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In `GDB` we have `-g` option to build the code for debugging purpose.
When code is built with `-g` option a symbol tale is associated with `exe` to help `gdb` to get variable's and function location information. 
When you ran `gdb`, this symbol table will help `gdb` to get to know the line number of code.
If you want to know whether your `exe` is having symbol table or not , try this command - `file <exe>`
This command will give you information whether your `exe` has a symbol table or not.
If your `exe` has a symbol table, result of this command will contain ----- not stripped key word.

Also if you try to attach `gdb` on `exe` without symbol table information , `gdb` will give you warning that it is unable to found symbol table and cannot attach `exe` with `gdb`.

When you attach to the `exe` with `gdb` - you need to type `run` command to run the `exe`.
Hope this helps.